# Django React Web App hosted on Digitalocean loading issue Only Home page show's

Tags: reactjs, django, hosting

I have hosted django react blogging web app, only two pages web app, it works fine locally, but when I host it online, the home page load, but when I go to another page, then page become blank, nothing show's, on reload show just a blink of the page, then show off again.
this is the link page to my app http://157.230.15.153/

Answer (score 0):

check your urls.py and views.py to make sure urls.py is properly pointing to the function in views.py and views.py returns the html file of your other page

Comment: This is class base view, and react is used in the front end, it is returning currectly.